# Reusing closed Kotlin's Channel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, channel, kotlin-flow

I want to use Channel as a Queue, but I need to clear it periodically. I didn't found `clear` method for the Channel and I make workaround with `Channel.cancel` and create new `Channel`, but it looks bad.

The question is:

**How can I implement using Kotlin's channel as a queue with cleaning? Recreating a channel looks not so good...**

Simplified context.

I have methods called by an external system: `enqueue(id: Int)` and `cancel()` and I don't have access to system that invokes these methods (React native methods in my case).

`enqueue(id: Int)` - enqueue `id` into the queue for processing (only one item at time can be processed) and starts processing the queue if is not started before.

`cancel()` - cancel pending processing but allow finishing current processing for current processing item.

My `Processor` is a singleton and `enqueue(id: Int)` can be called multiple times before canceling (to add items into queue) and after (for new processing).

My solution is to use channel as a queue and consume its items as a flow. `cancel()` will cancel the channel that allow current item processint to finish.

The problem is that after channel.cancel() channel is closed and I need to create new channel that is not so beautiful.

```
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val processor = Processor()
    repeat(3) { processor.enqueue(it) }
    delay(150)
    processor.cancelPending()
    delay(500)
    println("Run processing one more time.")
    repeat(3) { processor.enqueue(it) }
    delay(500)
}

class Processor : CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {
    private var channel = Channel<Int>(50)
    private var processJob: Job? = null

    fun enqueue(id: Int) {
        channel.offer(id)
        if (processJob?.isActive == true) return
        processJob = launch {
            channel.consumeAsFlow().collect { process(it) }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun process(id: Int) {
        delay(100)
        println("[$id] processed.")
    }

    fun cancelPending() {
        println("Cancel.")
        channel.cancel()
        channel = Channel(50)
    }
}
```